# How to put a rating stars in my web

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I want put a rating star in my page.  I'm making this but I don't know how to add the rating and show the average number,Do I have I to use local storage?

This is my code, it is very simple

Javascript Code

```
<script>

function signal(numero){

    for (var i=1; i<numero; i++){

        //document.write(i);
        document.getElementById("valor"+i).style.backgroundColor="red";
        //console.log(i);
    }
}

function outsignal(numero){


    for (var i=1; i<numero; i++){

        //document.write(i);
        document.getElementById("valor"+i).style.backgroundColor="";
        //console.log(i);
    }
}

function puntaje(numero){

    //var datos = new Array();



}


function puntaje(numero){


}
```

This is the HTML code

```
<body>

<div id="rating">

    <div id="valor1" onmouseover="signal(2)" onmouseout="outsignal(2)" onclick="puntaje(1)"></div>
    <div id="valor2" onmouseover="signal(3)" onmouseout="outsignal(3)" onclick="puntaje(2)"></div>
    <div id="valor3" onmouseover="signal(4)" onmouseout="outsignal(4)" onclick="puntaje(3)"></div>
    <div id="valor4" onmouseover="signal(5)" onmouseout="outsignal(5)" onclick="puntaje(4)"></div>
    <div id="valor5" onmouseover="signal(6)" onmouseout="outsignal(6)" onclick="puntaje(5)"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You need a lot more explaining to do before we can help you. "Putting rating stars" on your website is extremely vague.

Comment: Consider using FontAwesome - you can then use CSS to style the stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use some form of backend database if you want to keep track of the votes and display the average to every new user.

you can think of the 5 stars as another variant of a form selection box with 5 options.

you set up a javascript event that will post the user's selection for the specific item to the server and then the server will talk to the database and tell it to check if a record for this item exist if it does it will update that record with the new data else it will add a new record.

and during the creation of the page by the server it will ask the database what is the average value and graphically display it to the user.

Comment: mmm ok then I have to save the numbers in a database and  make the average there.